# What could cause getExternalFilesDir to return path from external SD card?

Tags: android, android-external-storage, android-fileprovider

I am using `context.getExternalFilesDir` to obtain the app's folder and that is on majority of devices the internal storage emulated card: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mypackage.com/files`

This is true and as per docs:

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the primary shared/external storage device where the application can place persistent files it owns.

Now, in a folder created on that `getExternalFilesDir` returned, I have a file `myimage.png` which I want to share with another app, calling `FileProvider.getUriForFile(...myimage.png)` throws an error on some devices and the error is like:

> Failed to find configured root that containts /storage/1234-1234/Android/data/mypackage.com/files

I have 2 questions:

1. what could cause to see the sdcard as `getExternalFilesDir` and not the internal storage path? I was not able to see it on my device, even if I have a sd card inserted in my device. Since the internal storage should be first to be returned.
2. Why does `getUriForFile` crash when using the path from external sdcard and how to fix it?

My files path contains `<external-files-path >` entry and works fine with no crash when using the `storage/emulated/0/Android` path

I saw some answer at [FileProvider error onHuawei devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895579/fileprovider-error-onhuawei-devices) that some devices return the path differently on `ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs` and other mention (https://github.com/linchaolong/ImagePicker/issues/10) that the `getUriForFile` uses internally the `ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs` call.

Comment: I don't see any evidence the `getExternalFilesDir` is returning a path to removeable storage as you claim. You say "probably sd card". Why do you think that?

Comment: I've added more insight on the error. The error shows a path which is different from the `/storage/emulated/0/Android` and has in it something that looks like the sd card's name. I say this because if I query the ExternalFilesDirs[] on a device, the sd card in it also has a similar name and path

Comment: I'd suggest re-wording your question. You might get more traction if you just describe the actual problem you are having and do not assume a root cause.